# Upgrade 2.2 app to honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am trying to upgrade my 2.2 app to honeycomb and run it on my xoom.  I have tried several things but can't get it to run in full screen on the xoom.

I have updated the manifest to include the following. I have also put all my layouts in a layout-xlarge folder.  I have tried various variants of the configs below all with no luck.

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                  android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="false"
                  android:largeScreens="false"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="false"/>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"
          android:targetSdkVersion="11"
          android:maxSdkVersion="11" />
```

Everything compiles, so there is something obvious I am missing here.  Anyone have an idea? I also check several times and project is compiling under 3.0.  I am using IntelliJ for dev.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a couple of things, add this to your manifest :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
```

also change android:anyDensity="false" to  android:anyDensity="true" and you should be all set.

Hope that helps.